# MySQL not starting in XAMPP - Port is not blocked

Tags: mysql, mariadb, xampp

I already verified port 3306 and it's not blocked port issue.

Also, checked Netstat and 3306 is not showing in the list

Upon starting MySQL XAMPP shows below error

[image: mysql error]

I checked mysql_error.log, below are the contents

```
2024-01-18 14:54:58 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 10.4.28-MariaDB source revision c8f2e9a5c0ac5905f28b050b7df5a9ffd914b7e7 as process 22364
2024-01-18 14:54:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2024-01-18 14:54:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2024-01-18 14:54:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.12
2024-01-18 14:54:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2024-01-18 14:54:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2024-01-18 14:54:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2024-01-18 14:54:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2024-01-18 14:55:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2024-01-18 14:55:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2024-01-18 14:55:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'D:\xampp12\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2024-01-18 14:55:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'D:\xampp12\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2024-01-18 14:55:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2024-01-18 14:55:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.28 started; log sequence number 18291975; transaction id 87804
2024-01-18 14:55:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from D:\xampp12\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2024-01-18 14:55:00 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2024-01-18 14:55:00 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

NetStat doesn't show 3306 as follows

[image: netstat]

Comment: It looks like MySQL was already running.  To check, Ctrl,ALT,DEL for Task Manager and look under Services for MySQL and if running, STOP it.  And try again.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I checked services and nothing coming up with search keyword mysql https://prnt.sc/E13s67fPuPEc

Comment: Browse through the list in alphabetical order, please.  Could be mysqld or maria%.